# Why use if-else if in C++?

Tags: c++, if-statement

Why would you use if-else statements if you can make another if statement?

Example with multiple ifs:

```
input = getInputFromUser()
if input is "Hello"
    greet()

if input is "Bye"
    sayGoodbye()

if input is "Hey"
    sayHi()
```

Example with else-if:

```
input = getInputFromUser()
if input is "Hello"
    greet()

else if input is "Bye"
    sayGoodbye()

else if input is "Hey"
    sayHi()
```

Comment: I was under the impression that programming-related questions were allowed here, *regardless of the level they were at*. This may seem like a basic question to many of us but I fail to see why it's considered "not a real question".

Comment: @litb - fewer keywords, but more complex conditions - the conditions have to explicitly exclude what the else would have excluded for you. Assuming else was appropriate, you'd end up with more words, numbers & symbols in total.

Comment: Not only that, but whether it does the same depend on what you execute as body of the first branch. You may change the condition variables... I think it's common to flip flags used in the condition, for example

Comment: I'm voting for reopening. This is a valid question and it's not *that* badly worded.

Comment: This is actually a very good question. With given example, should compiler be able to optimize multiple ifs and produce as efficient code as with else-if? Thanks to "non constructive" close-voters we may not see many interesting answers.

Answer (score 14):

If you have non-exclusive conditions:

```
if(a < 100)
{...}
else if (a < 200)
{...}
else if (a < 300)
....
```

this is very different from the same code without the "else"s...

Answer (score 13):

It's also more performant.

In your first example, *every* if will be checked, even if input is "Hello". So you have all three checks.

In your second example, execution will stop once it found a branch, so if the user types "Hello" it will be only one check instead of three.

The difference may not be much in your simple example, but imagine that you're executing a potentially expensive function and you might see the difference.

Answer (score 8):

you mean like this:

```
if (a == true && b == false && c == 1 && d == 0) {
    // run if true
}

if (a == false || b == true || c != 1 || d != 0) {
    // else
}
```

An else-statement would be much clearer and easier to maintain.

Comment: And less error-prone. Your two statements aren't perfect opposites - you need to change `&&` to `||` in the second one.

Comment: @Chris Lutz, found the mistake and fixed it around the same time as you :-)

Answer (score 7):

If you need to chose **exactly one** action from given set of actions, depending on some conditions, the natural and most clear choice is either switch (don't forget to break after each branch) or combination of if and else. When I write

```
if (conditon1)
{
    action1();
}
else if (condition2) 
{
    action2();
}
else if (conditon3)
{
    action3();
}
.
.
.
else {
    action_n();
}
```

it is clear to the reader that exactly one of actions is to be performed. And there is no possibility that because of mistake in conditions more than one action is performed.

Answer (score 0):

Following your same example if we use sequence of `if` conditions, whatever the input is it will run all 3 conditions. Replacing `sequence of if` with `if-else` conditions will run only first condition in best case whereas all 3 in worst case.

So conclude with that `if-else` will save our running time in most cases, therefore using `if-else` is preferred over using `sequence of if` conditions.

```
input = getInputFromUser()
if input is "Hello"
    greet()

if input is "Bye"
    sayGoodbye()

if input is "Hey"
    sayHi()
```